# How do you get the output in Ruby to sort in even and odd numbers?

Tags: ruby

I got this assignment in Codecademy. I want to print the even numbers.

```
print "Print any number:"
inpt = gets.chomp

def odd_or_even(num)
  if num % 2 == 0
    print "even"
  else
    print "odd"
  end
end
```

I do not get any output. Is the problem in the method, or how I've written the equation? I've tried changing both.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, I suggest you use the method [Integer#even?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F), (`if num.even? ...`) rather than [Integer#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 7):

You defined the method `odd_or_even` but never actually call it.

You have two options:

1. Take the more script-like approach and work with the input without the use of methods:

   ```
   print 'Print any number: '
   input = gets.to_i
   #              ^ convert the input (which is always a string) to an integer
   if input % 2 == 0
     puts 'even'
     # ^ is the same as `print` but adds a newline character at the end
     #   (unless the string ends with a newline character)
   else
     puts 'odd'
   end
   ```
2. If you want to use a method you'll have to define it and call it as well:

   ```
   def odd_or_even(num)
     if num % 2 == 0
       puts 'even'
     else
       puts 'odd'
     end
   end

   print 'Print any number: '
   input = gets.to_i
   odd_or_even(input)
   # ^ method is called here
   ```

Ruby also has a lot of build-in helpers. You can achieve the same result with the following two lines:

```
print 'Print any number: '
puts gets.to_i.odd? ? 'odd' : 'even'
```

**references:**

- [`#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) get user input
- [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) convert input to an integer
- [`Integer#odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F) check if the integer is odd
- [Ternary if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if): use inline of if `expression ? true : false`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check your input data.

Otherwise it may be a situation:

```
'abc'.to_i.even? #=> true
```

It's because non-digital `String#to_i` returns `0`.

As you see it's not good.

```
def odd_or_even(number)
  number.odd? ? 'odd' : 'even'
end

puts 'Print any number:'
input = gets.chomp

if input =~ /\D/
 puts 'It is not a number'
else
  puts "It's #{odd_or_even(input.to_i)}"
end
```

Firstly we validate data using regex. If it's not a number we will not check is it odd or even.

**Note:**

Very often we use `=~` [operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-3D~) to match `String` and `Regexp`.

`/\D/` means any non-digit character.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 20
loop do 
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 1
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer

Answer (score -1):

I see two issues with what you've posted - first `gets.chomp` is going to return a `string` and you really want an `integer`, so you'd want to do `gets.to_i` (or `Integer(gets)` if you want to guard against non-numeric inputs). The second is that `print` doesn't include a line break, so that could be the source of your "no output" issue - maybe try switching to `puts` instead?

Comment: You don't need `#chomp`, just `#to_i`

Comment: It is true that if you want to guard against invalid values you might want to use `Integer(variable)` instead, but there is still no reason to `#chomp`. `Integer("4\n") #=> 4` works perfectly fine.